# VS code for Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, vs-code

Suddenly started getting below error in my VS code while deploying components.

> Error: Parse error in file C:\Users\cccccr.sfdx\stash.json on line 1
>   FILE HAS NO CONTENT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be seen when the sfdx-project.json file contains incorrect definition.

Ensuring that the sfdx-project.json is correct, for example:

```
{
"packageDirectories": [
    {"path": "force-app","default": true}
  ],
"namespace": "",
"sourceApiVersion": "42.0"
}
```

resolved this issue.

Comment: Are "SFKID" and "peter" the same person?